# What went wrong with this answer?

Tags: discussion

This answer has been deleted.

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/36023/8146

The comment for it notes that the first version didn't keep in line with SE's professionalism.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: For what it's worth, you were right.

Comment: Bharal: You deserve an up vote for your deleted answer; but I obviously can't up vote a deleted answer, so why don't you pick one of your other answers so I can up vote that one to compensate.

Comment: Bharal: I just upvoted this one: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/36052/437

Answer (score 11):

When I saw the offensive flags I reviewed the post to see if a simple edit could fix it.  The unprofessional tone and snarky language ran through the first half of it, so I didn't see a simple edit.  Here are some examples of content that's out of line on a professional Q&A site:

> Look, Bob is a sociopath or autistic or something. Weird people can be good at IT because they get to memorise things and then be all wow with it.

First, you shouldn't be trying to diagnose Bob.  Second and more importantly, drawing an apparent equivalence between "sociopath" and "autistic" is seriously out of line, and "weird people" adds to the problem.  Third, while I'm not a medical professional, I don't think that's what autism means.

> Now, everybody hates this advice, but i will give it again anyway: life is too short to waste it with scum.

Bob may be scum, but you're not setting a great tone here with that choice of language.  (If it'd just been that I'd've ignored it; I'm *not* saying "scum is a dirty word on this site".  I *am* saying that it contributes to the case against this post.)

> Cue the people who will now tell you how you have to hang in there, he really loves you, the beatings will stop, you are a good wife... Oh wait, wrong group.

Starts off snarky ("cue the people...") and then you're drawing allusions to domestic violence?  Ick.

---

Some useful excerpts from [Be Nice](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice):

> Rudeness and belittling language are not okay. Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you. If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.

Do you think your tone matched "the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect" etc?  Do you think it was free of belittling language?

> Bigotry of any kind. Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few examples; when in doubt, just don't.)

Do you think the "autistic" remark was in line with this?

Please read the whole policy.  It's short.

---

If you edit this post to be more appropriate (I suggest cutting most of the first part and rewriting around the stuff you added in the second revision), we will review to see if it can be undeleted.  Note that the second revision added (only), so everything that was problematic in the first revision remains present.

Answer (score 7):

I would encourage you to read through the sections in the [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/stackexchange) regarding Stack Exchange's model. This details expectations of users on Stack Exchange.

Specifically, the entire section on "[Be Nice](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)" would be worth reading. I deleted the answer in question as multiple moderators agreed it violated much of that policy.

Comment: what, ah, "bit" of the section did i violate? i don't think i was rude to the OP of the post in question. i didn't use vulgar terms. i intended no bigotry, but if my use of the term "autistic" came across that way, let me know so i can 1. not do that again, 2. edit the question to remove that term.

Comment: "if my use of the term "autistic" came across that way, let me know so i can 1. not do that again" - yeah, don't do that again.

Answer (score 6):

The post reads more like something that would appear in a discussion forum, not a Stack Exchange answer that's been edited to represent the best quality content on the Internet:

> Look, Bob is a sociopath or autistic or something. Weird people can be good at IT because they get to memorise things and then be all wow with it. Whatever, a thick skin will be useful...

On the Internet, one of the things that convey social proof that you know what you're talking about is the words you use and your writing style. Objective, factual answers tend to work much better to meet this goal than words or phrases that make it sound like your opinion.

When writing answers on Stack Exchange, try to focus on content with an objective, clear focus. Avoid making assumptions about the asker's situation or giving personal advice. Hope this helps.

Comment: this is a reason to downvote the answer though, not a reason to delete it?